# rbind not working properly in loops

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

When I run this code at the R prompt, it works fine; I have 1 observation of 5 variable in `df_frame`.

```
st <- "AK"
df_frame <- data.frame(hospital=factor(),
        state=factor(),rank=numeric(),ties=numeric(),
        outcome=numeric())
temp <- data.frame(list(hospital="<NA>",
           state=st,rank=0,ties=0,outcome=0))
df_frame <- rbind(df_frame,temp)
```

When I use the same code in a loop, where I loop over a list of states:

```
for (st in states)  { 
  if (st %in% ranked_states) { 
       states_lst <- which(hosp_state == st) 
       df_frame <- rbind(df_frame, df_outcome[states_lst,]) 
       # Handle ties here 
  } else { 
    #df_frame[nrow(df_frame)+1,] <- c("<NA>",state,0,0,0) 
    #df_frame <- rbind(df_frame,
    #   c(as.character("<NA>"),as.character(state),0,0,0)) 
    temp <- data.frame(list(hospital="<NA>",
      state=st,rank=0,ties=0,outcome=0)) 
    df_frame <- rbind(df_frame,temp) 
  } 
}
```

I have these warnings:

```
    1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "<NA>") :
      invalid factor level, NA generated
    2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "AK") :
      invalid factor level, NA generated
```

No matter the magical combination of `factor` and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, it doesn't work.

Comment: a small *reproducible* example would help ...

Comment: setting `option(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` would be easiest. you can't just combine factor variables with different levels. that would be like binding `sex` and `state` -- r warns you that they are not compatible

Comment: @hfty
Here's an example of the loop
`
df_frame <-data.frame(hospital=factor(),state=factor())

for (st in states)
{
    if (st %in% ranked_states)
    {
        # this works fine
  states_lst <- which(hosp_state == st)
        df_frame <- rbind(df_frame, df_outcome[states_lst,])
    }
    else
    {
  # this replace <NA> and st by NA when used in a loop
  # on the prompt, it works fine
        temp <- data.frame(list(hospital="<NA>",state=st,rank=0,ties=0,outcome=0))
        df_frame <- rbind(df_frame,temp)
    }
}`

Comment: @rawr like I said previously, the provided code works on the R prompt and produce the expected result. df_frame is empty at this point. In a loop, df_frame has already a few rows in it.

Comment: make `hospital` and `state` character variables.

Comment: It finally worked! This line was wrong and was not giving the correct indexes.
states_lst <- which(hosp_state == st)

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same error. After several tries, my issue was that one of the data.frame, was not only a data.frame.

**class(your_dataframe)**

**Result:** `"grouped_df" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"`

I resolved by `your_dataframe <- as.data.frame(your_dataframe)`

P.S: That was not necessary on windows plataform only in Ubuntu